# How do I effect the changes when I convert NSDictionary to NSMutableDicitonary?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an `NSDicitonary` and I convert it into `NSMutableDictionary` . I'm trying to make changes in the `NSMutableDictionary` , now how can I effect those changes even in the `NSDictionary` ?

```
NSDictionary *dct=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"varun",@"name",@"9703507750",@"mobileNo",nil];

NSLog(@"dct : %@",dct);
dctMute=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

dctMute=[dct mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"dctMute :  %@",dctMute);

[dctMute setObject:@"hyderabad" forKey:@"city"];
[dctMute setObject:@"varun kumar" forKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"dctMute after adding city:  %@",dctMute);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'now how can I effect those changes even in the NSDictionary ?'

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the mutable copy.  Create a single mutable dictionary, then make it immutable like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dctMute = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
dctMute[@"foo"] = @"bar";
NSDictionary *immutableDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dctMute];
```

With new syntax, you can initialize this way too:

```
NSDictionary *immutableDictionary = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can drop your dctMute to your dct,

```
dct= dctMute;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert

```
NSDictionary *dic.....;
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDic = [dic mutableCopy];
```

You can do any changes with `NSMutableDictionary` but you can not do any changes with  `NSDictionary`. And when any changes are made with `NSMutableDictionary`  then it not effect to `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is "How can I make a NSDictionary from NSMutableDictionary?" The answer is simple - use the copy method. Copy always returns non-mutable object.

```
NSDictionary *dct=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"varun",@"name",@"9703507750",@"mobileNo",nil];

NSMutableDictionary dctMute=[dct mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"dctMute :  %@",dctMute);

[dctMute setObject:@"hyderabad" forKey:@"city"];
[dctMute setObject:@"varun kumar" forKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"dctMute after adding city:  %@",dctMute);

dct = [dctMute copy];
```